# SharePoint CSOM query return every field null

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom, caml

I want to retrive some fields with CAML Query - everytime when i execute query for example:

```
                query.ViewXml = string.Format(@"
                <View>
                    <Query>
                        <Where>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name='IDCardNumber' LookupId='TRUE'/>
                            <Value Type='Text'>12345</Value>
                        </Eq>
                        </Where>
                    </Query>
                    </View>
                    < ViewFields >
                       < FieldRef Name = 'Title' />
                    </ ViewFields >)");

                var items = list.GetItems(query);
                clientContext.Load(items);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Query returns 0 elements.

I tried to get all elements and with `CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();` - and in date I see correct count in list data, but FieldValues in elements look like this:
[Screenshot from VS Locals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4JUa.png)

In CAML Query Builder Tool:

```
   <Where>
      <IsNotNull>
         <FieldRef Name='Title' />
      </IsNotNull>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

Returns: [Screenshot from CAML Query Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AkPF.png)

How to get these values correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think the value type should be "Lookup" then your using the id of the lookup field (i.e. the id of the field in the alternative list)

```
<Eq>
  <FieldRef Name='IDCardNumber' LookupId='TRUE'/>
  <Value Type='Lookup'>12345</Value>
</Eq>
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewFields  goes in View

```
query.ViewXml = @"<View>
                <Query>
                    <Where>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='IDCardNumber' LookupId='TRUE'/>
                            <Value Type='Lookup'>12345</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    </Where>
                </Query>
                <ViewFields>
                    <FieldRef Name = 'Title'/>
                    <FieldRef Name = 'IDCardNumber'/>
                </ViewFields>
                </View>
                ";
```

Comment: TY, but still no items in the list

Comment: still get nulls

Comment: Check for internal name of this lookup column. You need to use column internal name.  In list go to list settings and click on that column IDCardNumber. In url check internal name of that column &Field=